# How to make motherboard beep via javascript?

Tags: javascript, applet, web-audio-api, motherboard

I'm developing a web application for employees of an enterprise and what I need is to make the motherboard to generate a sound on an event in a webpage in my application. I know about embedding a WAV file in my html and play it, but the constraint is that nearly all of my users don't have any speakers attached to their PCs. I've read about a solution that enables me to do that via an "applet". That's a way to do that, but you know the headache of installing Java on all the clients. So I want a more clear way to that.

Is there any one having such experience or any idea? I would love to hear about it.

Thanks a lot folks

Comment: It's impossible with JavaScript only.

Comment: I think its not possible with Javascript in Webpage you need to look at some things like javascript with node-webkit or some thing else to create a desktop based solution which can access hardware

Comment: @maremp I read that question. It doesn't have any idea about my situation about not having access to speakers.

Comment: http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm

Comment: @ArunKumar Thank you. Do you have any resource link about that?

Comment: @Hosein it's still a duplicate since the base premise doesn't change: JS cannot access the native beep functionality.

Comment: @Hosein you've tagged web-audio. Accessing to speakers is web audio. JavaScript doesn't have access to system's beep. I can't imagine how annoying it would be if it did. And FYI, newer systems (I  can  say for sure it's the case with Windows 7+  and OS X) don't have access to beep either, it's done as a system sound, which can be disabled.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes So is there another way like the applet solution to do that?

Comment: @Hosein You can check these out [System Beep](https://gist.github.com/taterbase/3154646) [BeepBeep](https://www.npmjs.org/package/beepbeep) [Html5 Desktop App with Node-Webkit](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-html5-desktop-apps-with-node-webkit--net-36296)